# Can I play/practice Fortnite's Battle Royale locally?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

Is it possible to be play Battle Royale in some sort of local environment?

I'm not too great at some aspects of the game and would like to practice in my own time and pace and not worry about a sniper bullet or the storm, similarly to how you can play CS:GO or Overwatch on any map, by yourself, with all sorts of various settings changed. Has anything like that been implemented (yet) ?

I haven't bought Save the World, just the f2p game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has been anounced that in patch 4.3 Fortnite will be adding a practice mode (called The Playground).

See http://uk.businessinsider.com/fortnite-practice-mode-2018-5

And the fortnite blog: https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/news/state-of-development-v5

> The Playground LTM will load you into the Battle Royale Map with some adjusted settings.
>
> Battle and build to your heart's content with an extended period of time to roam around the map as well as increased resource generation. All treasure chests and ammo crates will be spawned, try droppin’ in different spots and scope out the loot. Friendly fire is on so you can scrimmage with your squad (up to 4 friends per match), but fear not you’ll respawn immediately.

Comment: Playground mode is NOW here! (4.5)

Comment: @GamerM  Yay. I just tried it, it's great :D

Comment: Quick Question. Is it on all platforms?(Only tried it on console)

Comment: Windows (I run it on that), Xbox, Nintendo Switch, PS4, iOS and Mac @GamerM see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortnite

Comment: Okay then, So all of them. My friend told me it was only on Xbox  1 day before it came.

Answer (score 5):

This will eventually be supported as part of Fortnite Battle Royale's *Custom Matchmaking* feature, which is currently in private testing.

[Official reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/FortNiteBR/comments/7k0enn/what_is_custom_matchmaking_private_matches/) and [the same post on the Epic Games forums](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/forums/news/announcements/118859-what-is-custom-matchmaking-private-matches):

> We are re-enabling the "Custom Matchmaking" button on PC. Why?
>
> To test private matches. PC players will be able to see the button, but it cannot be used by anyone outside our private tests. We are going to be leaving the button on as we continue to test the private match feature.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it means it's coming though ?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no release date announced yet, but at least we know that it is planned and confirmed.

Comment: Update: The Fortnite Twitter began tested private servers created by some well-known streamers.

Answer (score 1):

Fortnite's Battle Royale mode is the one you have and currently the only free version of it. So unless you pay to buy the PvE versions you are at risk of the storm and other players.

Comment: out of date now unfortunately.  Playground has been added permanently